# Proper way to authenticate graphql with facebook

Tags: django, authentication, graphql, ariadne-graphql

I'm doing web application using graphql (ariadne) + Django. Now I want to integrate it with Facebook authentication without using DRF. So I wanted to use jwt. Is there any good practice or suggestions ? What is the proper way of doing authentication in graphql ?

Comment: https://github.com/flavors/django-graphql-social-auth good package built on top of social python auth that is widely used

Comment: Did you able to do it?

Comment: @Serenity well, for my case i managed to restrict user authentication using a web server and it's authentication mechanism

Comment: sorry i did not get you. Do you mean you used rest api for authentication and ariadne for other tasks?

Comment: Well ariadne endpoint works on Django server right ?. So just checking `request.user.is_authenticated` in resolver did the work for my case. That way requests sending from Django itself has session cookie when sending request. You can check this by `includeCredentials` in ariadne playground settings.

Comment: I tried https://github.com/flavors/django-graphql-social-auth, but what ever ant accessToken i input in it , it retruns th same user. Probably i need to asociate users with thier accessTokens?!